# How to export a pyspark mlib machine learning model and deploy as a web service?

Tags: web-services, rest, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a linear regression model build using spark mlib. Now i want to export the model and use the model via a web service.
I was looking into PMML was not able to find a proper source as how can I use it. Do I need to install any specific PMML library or how can it be done.

The same model i tried exporting as a pickle file using joblib and  deployed it as a web service via flask. I want to do something similar for the model developed in Spark mlib.

Can anyone please help me out or point me to correct source?

Answer (score 0):

For a simple REST web service using PMML you could have a look at https://github.com/openscoring/openscoring. It uses JAVA though. For Python+Flask I have no idea but PMML is nothing more than a XML file which needs to be evaluated. So you could try to write your own Python logic to do it. I've also found this https://github.com/maxkferg/pmml-scoring-engine but it doesn't have much stars.

It is noted though that PMML is quite limited in its usage. Not all models are supported e.g. ALS. Another approach is to deploy a PySpark application via its binaries. I blogged about this [here](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/operationalizing-pyspark-data-science-models-on-pivotal-cloud-foundry). We deployed it using  Cloud Foundry but you can use the buildpack to deploy it on Heroku as well if you need a public endpoint. Hope this helps.